# Mac OS X 10.xで起動時に特定のコマンドを実行するには

Tags: macos

Mac OS Xで起動時に特定のコマンドを実行させたいです。
具体的には

```
apachectl start
mysql.server start
```

です。
それぞれhomebrew経由でインストールされており、apacheは特権ポートを利用するため特権ユーザでの起動が必要です。
スタートアップスクリプトなどを置く場所があるのでしょうか？

下記のスレッドではlaunchctlを利用する方法が掲載されていました。
しかし内容が古く(10.6)、自分もmac portsを利用していた頃はlaunchctlを使っていましたが、今でもそういったやり方になるのでしょうか？
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564394/add-a-start-up-item-via-command-line-mac

Comment: たとえばこれとかいかがでしょう。 [Qiita - OS X で起動時に任意のコマンドを実行する](http://qiita.com/bsdhack/items/5ef36bd62b88c9e8197e)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

参考：

- homebrew の Apache 自動起動設定 http://kazuomabuo.hatenablog.jp/entry/2014/06/17/232728
- brew servicesを使ってHomebrewでインストールしたMySQLを自動起動する http://cockscomb.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/04/05/153451